# Pagination in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, pagination, azure-data-factory, webapi

I'm trying to fetch data from API where the result is split over multiple pages, The response is something as below.

> {
> "story_count": 212,
> "next": "?page=11",
> "previous": "?page=9",
> "results": [{

I'm stuck how to fetch data for second and many more pages to come till I get next value as NULL. I'm not sure how to use the pagination function in the copy activity for this case, please help many thanks !

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible in Copy activity, and would be challenging in Data Flow as well. You'll need to create some process to process a page of results at a time, then aggregate the results.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this with ADF. Instead I used an Azure Databricks notebook (Pyspark) to extract and transform the JSON and wrote it straight to azure sql. I was very surprised by the speed of insertion to azure sql, it literally went 4 times as fast as I was used to. Another benefit using this approach is the use of multithreading and storing the access token into the session header (enabling reuse of TCP connection). Nevertheless very cubersome approach but works for me.

Comment: Hey @Luukv93 can you share your code ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the response from API needs to be modified to get in below format

{
"story_count": 212,
"next": "2",
"previous": null,
"results": []
}

Then, in ADF, the query parameters can be passed as below

```
QueryParameters['page']: $['next']
```